# Missing Dart null checking shorthand?

Tags: dart, null-check, null-coalescing

I know that Dart has the null checking shorthands

```
x = y ?? z;
```

and

```
x = y?.z;
```

But what if I have a statement like

```
x = (y != null) ? SomeClass(y) : z;
```

I don't want to pass `null` to the `SomeClass` constructor - so in that case I want `x` to be set to `z` (in my specific situation `z` happens to be `null`).

I can't figure out how/if I can use any of the shorthands in this scenario, or if I'm stuck with the direct null check.

Comment: There is no shorthand for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: there is no shorthand. Your code is good.

The really short answer is: it depends. ;)

If you think about the surrounding codebase you can come up with a different architecture overall.

You may as well pass null to the constructor

```
x = SomeClass(y);
```

and then give a reasonable default in your initializer list:

```
class SomeClass {
  dynamic _value;

  SomeClass(value) _value = value ?? ''; 
}
```

or throw an exception:

```
var nullError = Exception('Null value not allowed');

class SomeClass {
  dynamic _value;

  SomeClass(value) _value = value ?? (throw nullError);
}
```

though a more idiomatic way would be this:

```
class SomeClass {
  dynamic _value;

  SomeClass(value) {
    ArgumentError.checkNotNull(value);
    _value = value;
}
```

As I know nothing about the rest of your code, I cannot give you the right answer.
But I suggest you to ask yourself:

- *Where does this z value come from? What is its meaning?*
  (If you're in big project, you may use Dependency Injection or Factories.)
- *Maybe I have a view component, where empty strings are more useful than nulls?*

These are some things I would ask myself.
But if you're hacking a quick script, this maybe a long shot.
You may have already finished your task by now, and maybe you really had no need for a shorthand in the first place.

Comment: That's one long short answer! ;) For this specific task I think the best option is to just keep the direct null check, but your points are good to keep in mind.

Comment: The answer was short. But then I elaborated on that :P